# How to make subplots with specific and shared indexes?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I am training with pandas and matplotlib, and I did myself this sample :

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# This following dictionnary are datas of videos of planes
# Models are 330 or 550, it is the name of the plane
# duree is the duration of the video, in seconds.

d={
    'modele':[330,550,550,330,550,550,550],
    'source':['client','prod','prod','prod','client', 'prod', 'prod'],
    'duree':[200,300,400,80,30,800,20]
}

df=pd.DataFrame(d)
df2 = df.set_index(['modele']).groupby(['source', 'modele']).plot.bar()
```

Out :

[Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QMSqd.png)

I watched a lot of documentation but i guess there is something i am missing.
I would like to make 2 subplot :

1. One for 550 model :

- One bar for 'client', in red, with its value equals to the meaning of the durations of 550 AND 'client' videos.
- The same in green for 'prod'

2. The other one for 330 : the same as 550.

I think that a simple example will help me a lot.

Comment: `df.plot.bar()` takes in an `ax` parameter. You could create 2 subplots using the `plt.subplots` function, which returns a number of axes. Then you can run the `df.plot.bar` multiple times, specifying what data goes to which axis

Comment: I am sorry, I don't know where to set plt.subplots(). I didn't found already good documentation for the link matplotlib/pandas. I am only using DataFrame.XXX()

Comment: Please see: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/visualization.html#using-layout-and-targeting-multiple-axes